# Do not understand why I keep getting this error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I know this is a routing error but I can't find any errors in my routes.

```
  // comments
  Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

This is the controller.

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /comments
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}
```

Thank you in advance.  It is probably an easy 15 points to someone.

Comment: What url are you trying? What's your vhost setup? What's in your .htaccess? (assuming you're using apache)

Comment: desk.dev:8000/comments

Comment: What's the name of your controller? The class should have name `CommentsController` and the file should have name `CommentsController.php`

Comment: I know class CommentsController extends BaseController

Comment: Can you post your complete `routes.php` file?

Comment: That is the full file I am just working on a feature that will be added to the site when I am done.

Comment: Does the error appears after sending any form?

Comment: I don't know I can't view the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs when you try to submit your form. When you use:

```
Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

it's only for `GET` request and if you try submit your form probably you use `POST` method

You could add to your routes:

```
Route::post('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

if you want to route to the same method in your controller or create another method and route to it.

You can also use:

```
Route::any('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

if you don't care about method - all requests (including POST and GET) would be directed to the route.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the full `routes.php` file is shown, you need to add the PHP opening brackets at the top:

```
<?php

// comments
Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

Omitting that will give you exactly the error you're getting.

Comment: Then it means that your `routes.php` file is not being loaded. Are you using the default setup?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things I can think of. The first is yours route:

```
Route::get('/comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

I think it could be either:

```
Route::get('comments', 'CommentsController@index'); // Note the omitted /
Route::get('comments', array('as' => 'comments', 'uses' => 'CommentsController@index');
```

In theory, that should fix the issue, but if not, there's one more thing I do differently when using views. You have:

```
return View::make('comments.create');
```

I use:

```
return View::make('comments/create');
```

Where the folder structure would be:

```
views->comments->create.blade.php
```

Now I have no idea if/how that would affect it, give those a try.

Comment: Thanks but that did not fix it.

Comment: Hmm. Very strange... Now do you only have the one route? Like do you have `Route::get("/", "HomeController@showWelcome")?

Comment: I did find these Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index');
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('/login', ['before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'AuthController@authenticate']);
Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Comment: I've tried to replicate your error by adding a CommentsController, new Route and new View to an existing project of mine, but it just works. Tbh, I'm not sure what's going on. Sorry I couldn't help more, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an `auth` filter on this route. If your `AuthController` is not set up, or is missing the `login` method, you will get a `NotFoundHttpException` when the `auth` filter in `filter.php` tries to redirect to your login page.