# My new route is causing an error and I need help finding it

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-routing

So the error I am getting is Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException.

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index');
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('/login', ['before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'AuthController@authenticate']);
Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function() {

$noIndex = [ 'except' => ['index'] ];
$noShow = [ 'except' => ['show'] ];

Route::get('/dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard');

Route::get('/test', 'MessageController@index');
```

Here is the controller:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /test
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('test.index');
}
```

Comment: Is the controller namespaced? You also don't need the leading `/` on your route, `Route::get('test'...` is fine

Comment: no it is not it is just sitting in the controller folder with the base controller and the pages controller.

Comment: What's the URL you are using? Can you paste the output of `php artisan routes`?

Comment: This question is a likely duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017372/routing-issue-causing-symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhtt/26020851?noredirect=1#comment40756211_26020851), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892238/do-not-understand-why-i-keep-getting-this-error-symfony-component-httpkerne?rq=1), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997303/i-am-getting-symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-methodnotallowedhttp?rq=1). If you are the same poster, you'll have better luck keeping this in one thread.

Comment: @lowerends here you go | MessageController@index            | auth           |               |

Comment: @damiani the questions are similar but I didn't ask them and they don't help anyone because they don't have answers.

Comment: Ok, looks like you're using a `before` `auth` filter. Can you post your complete `routes.php` file?

Comment: ...and please post what URL you are using, as requested above, and your Virtual Host setting. It's possible your Virtual Host setting is incorrect, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593892/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhttpexception-laravel?rq=1).

Comment: @lowerends i don't have access to the other routes right now my project manager is sick.

Comment: @damiani I apologize I don't see that asked above here it is desk.dev:8000/test

Comment: 1) Please post the contents of `public/.htaccess`; and (2) are you running this using Homestead and a Vagrant virtual machine?

Comment: @damiani 1. <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule> 2. yes I am currently using homestead and vagrant virtual machine

Comment: OK, please post the contents of your `Homestead.yaml` file from the Homestead directory.

Comment: ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public
      
    - map: desk.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/desk/public

    - map: web.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/website/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

Comment: Are the routes of your other sites, `test.app` and `web.dev`, working?

Comment: yes they are working

Comment: Post your whole `routes.php` file (when your project manager is feeling better :) ), post your `auth` filter, and/or try removing your `auth` filter. The problem could be in there.

Comment: Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index');
Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('/login', ['before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'AuthController@authenticate']);
Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function() {

    $noIndex = [ 'except' => ['index'] ];
    $noShow = [ 'except' => ['show'] ];

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard');
    Route::get('/test', 'MessageController@index');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we have some more complete information regarding your **routes.php** setup, it's possible that the problem is due to the `auth` filter.

(I'm assuming you left off the final `});` from your **routes.php** above.)

Try removing the `before` filter (or change it temporarily to `['before' => 'none']`) and reload `desk.dev:8000/test`. Make sure you don't simply hit reload on the current error page, since it may be pointing to `desk.dev:8000/login`.

If your `AuthController` is not set up, or is missing the `login` method, you will get a `NotFoundHttpException` when the `auth` filter in `filter.php` tries to redirect to your login page, with:

```
return Redirect::guest('login');
```